# How to deploy Vite react app in AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, vite

I want to deploy my react app which was built using vite into AWS Amplify but the build is failing. Here's how my package.json looks

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "author": "ashiqdey",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "vite": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

What wrong I am doing?

[image]

---

Edit : Here's my yml file, After getting vite command not found error I had added npm i vite -g, still no luck
[image]

After adding the npm i vite I am getting this error
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Developing software: 49% time spent on cloud configuration, 49% on build scripts, 2% writing code. And this is with all the amazing new tools becoming available.

Your package file correct and just like mine (although my vite is older) so this answer may not help you.

The `amplify.yml` has a preBuild step that should be doing a `yarn install` (or `npm install`), so vite and other packages will be downloaded.

I have `amplify.yml` in the root of my project because I changed `baseDirectory: /` to `baseDirectory: /dist`.

I have a `vite.config.ts`:

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: './runtimeConfig',
        replacement: './runtimeConfig.browser',
      },
    ]
  },
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './src/test/setup.ts',
  }
})
```

My `index.html` has some extra for vite:

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script>
    window.global = window;
    window.process = {
      env: { DEBUG: undefined },
    };
    var exports = {};
  </script>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
</body>
```

**EDIT**
Here's my `amplify.yml` file:

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist/
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: I am getting the error in build process itself. vite command not  found, the I added npm I vite -g in preBuild config. Still no luck

Comment: Odd, looks like npm is failing. In AWS Amplify console, App settings -> Build settings, check your "Build image settings". I'm set to 'latest' for Amplify CLI, no other package overrides.

Comment: I had added the yml file can you suggest where to make the changes? @Dave

Comment: I just update `baseDirectory` from `/` to `dist/`. I updated the answer with the whole file for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a video that has helped me with this issue using the amplify CLI, pre-built the backend definitions changed some directories and build commands for vite.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rvl4nua2IJw

I had many issues prior to this video so hopefully it helps for you.
Seems like amplify hasn't fully embraced vite yet
Here is my amplify.yml afterwards:

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
        
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post (https://www.nextsteps.dev/posts/aws-amplify-getting-started-with-vite) with more in-depth links and references, but the TLDR is that for the Amplify libraries to run correctly, a couple of changes need to be added to the project. It's a problem with the AWS SDK.

1. in the index.html in the `<body>` tag

```
<script>
      // AWS Amplify needs this to work. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3673
      const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== "undefined";
      const isGlobal = () => typeof global !== "undefined";
      if (!isGlobal() && isBrowser()) {
        var global = window;
      }
</script>
```

2. add a `resolve` object to the `vite.config.js`

```
    resolve: {
    alias: {
      "./runtimeConfig": "./runtimeConfig.browser",
    },
},
```

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I think I followed the rules. The two pieces of code needed to deploy a vite project are the answer here and the real cause of the issue. Did I miss something?